# remove output space in C++

Tags: c++11, formatting, output

I am new in cpp language. I trying solve a problem on Insertion sort. However, presentation error happened while submit to online judge. in program I have to show intermediate sequence in a line for each step of Insertion sort. Here is my code so far:

```
void InsertionSort(int *arr, int n)
{

for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    int key = arr[i];
    int j = i - 1;
    while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key)
    {

        arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
        j--;
    }

    arr[j + 1] = key;
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        cout << arr[k] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3<Here is space.want to remove it> 
1 2 3<Here is space.want to remove it>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Instead of for each element doing `cout << arr[k] << " ";`, do that for each element except for the last one. Then, output the last one with a newline.

Comment: @Fureeish would you plz show/explain me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `std::cout << arr[k] << ' '` all `n` elements. Apply that to every single one *except for the last one*. Then, output that element, but instead of having it followed by a space, have it followed by `'\n'` or `std::endl`, preferably the former one:

```
for (int k = 0; k < n - 1; k++)
    cout << arr[k] << " ";
cout << arr[n - 1] << '\n';
```

Notice the `n - 1` instead of `n` in the `for()` loop condition. This will apply the body for all the element *except for the last one*.

Then, we need to treat the last element (represented by the `n - 1`th index) differently - we don't want to print it followed by a `" "`, but rathar a newline. That's why we do `<< '\n';`. Note that `std::endl` would work too, but it's unnecessary. I encourage you to read about [`std::endl` vs `'\n'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n).